# Cannot figure out how to separate dollars from cents

Tags: python

I have been given a program with only a main function defined and i must add in additional functions to make the program work. I am currently stuck on the part where i have to make the amount of coins turn into a dollar amount and only show the dollars not the remaining cents. 
Really what i am looking for is help starting out def get_dollars. Anything will be much appreciated.

```
  def main():
        pennies = get_input1("Enter pennies : ")
        nickels = get_input2("Enter nickels : ")
        dimes = get_input3("Enter dimes : ")
        quarters = get_input4("Enter quarters : ")

        print("You entered : ")
        print("\tPennies  : " , pennies)
        print("\tNickels  : " , nickels)
        print("\tDimes    : " , dimes)
        print("\tQuarters : " , quarters)


        total_value = get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
        dollars = get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)
        left_over_cents = get_left_over_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters)

        print("Total = $", total_value, sep="")
        print("You have", dollars, "dollars and", left_over_cents, "cent(s)")

    def get_input1(pennies):
        pennies = input("Enter Pennies: ")
        if int(pennies) < 0:
            print('Error: money cannot be negative')
            pennies = int(input('Enter correct amount of pennies: '))
        return pennies
    def get_input2(nickels):
        nickels = input("Enter nickels: ")
        if int(nickels) < 0:
            print('Error: money cannot be negative')
            pennies = int(input('Enter correct amount of nickels: '))
        return nickels
    def get_input3(dimes):
        dimes = input("Enter dimes: ")
        if int(dimes) < 0:
            print('Error: money cannot be negative')
            pennies = int(input('Enter correct amount of dimes: '))
        return dimes
    def get_input4(quarters):
        quarters = input("Enter quarters: ")
        if int(quarters) < 0:
            print('Error: money cannot be negative')
            pennies = int(input('Enter correct amount of quarters: '))
        return quarters
    def get_total(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):

        amount_pennies = (int(pennies) * .01)
        amount_nickels = (int(nickels) * .05)
        amount_dimes = (int(dimes) * .10)
        amount_quarters = (int(quarters) * .25)
    def get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):

    main()
```

Comment: pro tip 1,2 and 3: don't name your functions get_input3 - make it meaningful, don't name a function main(), you already have __main__ for that, 3 comment your functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adds up the value in pennies and then divides by 100 to get dollars

```
def get_dollars(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    return ( int(pennies) + 5*int(nickels) 
            + 10*int(dimes) + 25*int(quarters) )//100
```

Because `//` is integer division, the left-over penny amounts are discarded.

As an example:

```
>>> get_dollars('104', '44', '10', '4')
5
```

#### Retrieving both dollars and cents

```
def get_dollars_and_cents(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters):
    total = int(pennies) + 5*int(nickels) + 10*int(dimes) + 25*int(quarters)
    return total // 100, total % 100
```

Example:

```
>>> get_dollars_and_cents('104', '44', '10', '4')
(5, 24)
```

Or,

```
>>> dollars, cents = get_dollars_and_cents('104', '44', '10', '4')
>>> print('dollars=', dollars, 'cents=', cents)
dollars= 5 cents= 24
```

Comment: i really appreciate the help, but wouldnt using this method make it harder to find the remaining cents since they are discarded?